# Study purpose: Set value true/false by clicking on task

Tags: php, arrays, json, vue.js

Hello i have component Vue, taskdone.php and todo.json.

At moment i can create new tasks from input in vue(frontend), send it on php(backend) and store it in todo.json.

I m trying to add feature that i click on text with the task and the value "completed" change from true to false but dont work.

Can someone explain me the fixes and the reason ?

Thanks for your time

todo.VUE

```
<script >
import axios from 'axios';
const API_URL = "http://localhost/";
export default {
data(){
  return{
    task : "",
    todoList : []
  }
},
methods: {
  getAll(){
    axios.get(API_URL + "api.php")
    .then(res => {
      const data = res.data;
      this.todoList = data;
    });

  },
  addNew(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const params = { params: {
      "newTask" : this.task
    }};
    axios.get(API_URL + "newtask.php",params)
    .then(() => {
      this.getAll();
    })
    this.task = "";
  },
  taskDone(i){
    const params = { params: {
      "id" : i
    }}
    axios.get(API_URL + "newtask.php", params)
    console.log(i);
  }
},
mounted(){
  this.getAll();
}
}


</script>

<template>
    <form action="" @submit="addNew">
      <label for="">Inserisci task: </label>
      <input type="text" v-model="task">
      <input type="submit" value="Add" >
    </form>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(task,index) in todoList" :key="index" :class="task.completed == true ? 'taskDone': ''" @click="taskDone(index)">
        {{ task.text }}
        {{ task.completed }}
      </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<style scoped>
.taskDone{
  text-decoration:line-through;
}

</style>
```

taskdone.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:5173");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");

header("Content-Type: application/json");
$id = $_GET["id"];

$jsonTodoList = file_get_contents("todo.json");
$todoList = json_decode($jsonTodoList);

$todoList=$todoList[$id]["completed"] = !$todoList[$id]["completed"];


$jsonTodoList = json_encode($todoList);
file_put_contents("todo.json" , $jsonTodoList);
```

todo.json

```
[
{"text":"take a break",
 "completed":false
},
{"text":"buy a coffee",
"completed":false
}
]
```

Comment: I can't help you with your specific problem, but you should be able to debug/troubleshoot this with your browser tools. First, check for JavaScript or HTTP errors. Second inspect the payload that is being sent to and from the server, is it what you expect?

Comment: I dont have error or something else :S

Comment: And what about the payloads?